# foreach in PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach, prepared-statement

I would like to have a bit of clarification about prepared statements, and how they behave when assembled in other ways.
The sample code below is from Straight out [this W3 entry](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp). My problem is that, having many more values than the four provided in this example, I'd love to store them in an array and then run a foreach to prepare each string.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) 
VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

// insert a row
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row
$firstname = "Mary";
etc
```

Would the edit below be safe for application, or does it crack the whole point of prepared statements?

```
$stuff = array("firstname", "lastname", "email");
foreach ($stuff as $singlestuff) {
$singlestuff1 = ':'.$singlestuff;
$singlestuff2 = '$'.$singlestuff;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests ($singlestuff1) ) VALUES ($singlestuff2)");
$stmt->bindParam($singlestuff1, $singlestuff2);
}
```

Sorry for any macroscopic mistake, the code is just an illustration of the concept.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read php-manuals for functions you use. You will find things that they don't tell in w3schools.

Comment: where is the end of your for/each squiggly? You bind individually, but hard to say what you are even doing without the squiggly. It is as if the concept of binding generates too high a source code line count, that is bothering you

Comment: @Drew Sorry about the foreach end, just edited the code above. Anyway I've been thinking about this workaround to have a flexible script which could be run with different forms. So if every form has its own list of inputs, having a foreach would definitely speed up the process both in developing and updating.  
But then again, I honestly am not sure if this code would then open security issues or worse, so can you please explain a bit further your point? Would you rather suggest to work on the prepared statement as is?

Comment: Is my answer below useful, or should I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Bind within the foreach loop, assumed the variables exist:

```
foreach ($stuff as $singlestuff) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':' . $singlestuff, $$singlestuff);
}
```